# mv directory to a device partition's subdirectory, e.g. mv directory /dev/partition/subdirectory?

Tags: files, mount, devices

**What does the following /dev related syntax do?**

```
mv directory /dev/partition/subdirectory
```

Does this just make a new 'subdirectory' in the 'partition' device or what?  I guess I've never seen a subdirectory in a disk partition.  Is there any special behavior or is this just a normal subdirectory?

This code is from [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27075/can-i-share-mysql-database-files-with-windows-on-dual-boot#57817) 6 year old post which I hope to implement related to dual boot MySQL sharing the same data dictionary.

---

**For reference**, here is the complete post with instructions, which itself is from an earlier post referenced at the bottom of it:

> Yes, it works but with some quirks. MySQL uses the same fileformats
>   across platforms so all you need is to share the data directory. One
>   problem is that the data directory need to have mysql as owner and
>   group in ubuntu. And Windows is case-insensitive and Linux is
>   case-sensitive so keep all names uniform: either the whole name
>   lowercase or uppercase but do not mix them.
>
> From start to finish; if you already have things set up this might
>   need some tweaking to fit your setup:
>
> ```
> Install and setup MySQL on both systems.
>
> Stop the mysql server if it is running.
>
> Make a new NTFS partition. Mark the device name (let's call it sdXN for now).
>
> Move the mysql data directory from Ubuntu to the new partition.
>
> sudo mv /var/lib/mysql /dev/{sdXN}/mysql_data
>
> Make a new mysql directory
>
> sudo mkdir /var/lib/mysql
>
> Mount the NTFS partition at /var/lib/mysql. Change the devicename to what it got when you created the NTFS partition.
>
> sudo mount /dev/{sdXN} /var/lib/mysql -t ntfs-3g -o uid=mysql,gid=mysql,umask=0077
>
> To automount on boot find the partition UUID and locale and edit /etc/fstab.
>
> ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid
> locale -a
> sudo gedit /etc/fstab   
> UUID={number_found_with_the_ls-l} /var/lib/mysql ntfs-3g uid=mysql,gid=mysql,umask=0077,locale={your_locale}.utf8  0  0
>
> Change the 'datadir' path in /etc/mysql/my.cnf to point to /var/lib/mysql/mysql_data
>
> Start the mysql server and test it.
>
> Edit the Windows config file (my.ini) and set 'datadir' to X:/mysql_data (replace X: for where you mount it under Windows).
> ```
>
> Compiled from topic 1442148 on UF.org.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those instructions are wrong, and you'll get an error

eg

```
% ls -l /dev/vda1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 253, 1 Sep 16 17:45 /dev/vda1
% mkdir X
% sudo mv X /dev/vda1/X
mv: failed to access '/dev/vda1/X': Not a directory
```

You just can't do what that says.